# Where is Flutter's Navigator declared?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-material

When creating a Flutter application,
we use a Navigator to move back and forth between screens.

In my application, I have some class instances that
I want to share with all child widgets in the hierarchy.

An example is a Data Base driver class (stateful)
which holds all functionality of reading/writing to the actual database.

Currently - the 'main' function is initializing it,
then the resulting object is passed through all
constructors of the participating widgets.

**How do I make it behave like the Navigator
so it would be available in the global scope
without importing it or passing it through a chain of constructors?**

I would gladly accept any other approaches,
and still, if you can also address the exact question - I would be grateful :)

I opened the code of Navigator, Stateless and Stateful widgets,
I tried to google for the source of that Navigator instance
but came up with nothing helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html)?

From the docs:

> Base class for widgets that efficiently propagate information down the tree.

Create `DataBaseDriver` class as inherited Widget class, access it in its child class using `context` as `DataBaseDriver.of(context)`

Comment: You have to create the static ".of" method as well... that's not automatic.